# Flink Checkpoint Rolling policy not rolling over file based on file size limit defined

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using Flink S3 sink and I have created custom Checkpoint rolling policy to define rolling condition based on File size.

As per below code, none of my S3 part file size should cross 100KB of size but I am seeing file size of upto 2 mb in my s3 bucket. What could be the reason behind that? How can I enforce Flink output file size should not cross 100KB of size?

```
 FileSink.forBulkFormat(s3SinkPath, new ParquetWriterFactory<>(builder))
                    .withBucketAssigner(new CustomDateTimeBucketAssigner())
                    .withRollingPolicy(new CustomCheckpointRollingPolicy())
                    .build(); 





 public class CustomCheckpointRollingPolicy<IN, BucketID> extends CheckpointRollingPolicy<IN, BucketID> {

   

    private static final long maxSize = 100_000;  // 100KB

  


    @Override
    public boolean shouldRollOnEvent(PartFileInfo<BucketID> partFileState, IN element) throws IOException {
        return partFileState.getSize() >= maxSize;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldRollOnProcessingTime(PartFileInfo<BucketID> partFileState, long currentTime) throws IOException {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your custom rolling policy does not work as expected is that in fact the `partFileState.getSize()` is always 4 in your case.

The reason for this is that the `ParquetWriterFactory` creates an instance of `ParquetBulkWriter` around the file output stream and it does not expose the actual buffer size of internal `parquetWriter`. The `BulkPartWriter` used by default `ParquetBulkWriter` simply extends from `OutputStreamBasedPartFileWriter`, which implements `getSize()` method as

```
    @Override
    public long getSize() throws IOException {
        return currentPartStream.getPos();
    }
```

However, it returns current position in output stream which is always 4 since the `ParquetWriter` does not send the data to output stream immediately but instead stores in buffer and flushes only when the page size / row groupd size reaches the target value, configured by `AvroParquetWriter`.

In order to be able to get the actual data size (not compressed, however, thus not actually matching the parquet file size), you will need to provide your custom `ParquetWriterFactory`, which will return the custom size-aware `ParquetBulkWriter` with an additionally exposed method

```
    /**
     * @return the total size of data written to the file and buffered in memory
     */
    public Long getSize() {
        return this.parquetWriter.getDataSize();
    }
```

and implement your custom `BulkPartWriter`, which will get the data size (NOT the parquet file size!) from the writer above:

```
    @Override
    public long getSize() throws IOException {
        return ((SizeAwareParquetBulkWriter) writer).getSize();
    }
```

Comment: I am using Flink 14.0 and BulkPartWriter class is declared as final/non public in that version which means it cant be extended to add custom implementation. Are you sure this is the only way to achieve this? Also all Flink documentation says we are allowed to add custom checkpointRollingPolicy based on file size/time which makes me assume that we should have straightforward way to do that

Comment: I was not talking bout extending the `BulkPartWriter`, I meant providing your custom implementation of `BulkPartWriter`, extending `OutputStreamBasedPartFileWriter`.

Alternatively, you can try to tweak your parquet settings and set page size and row group size rather low, around 100KB